# Retrieve a list of users and their verified authentication factors (MFA)

Tags: rest-api, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

We have users enrolled in multi-factor authentication (MFA). I need to know verified authentication methods (email, phone number, ...) for each user. I tried retrieving the info via REST API:

```
/query/?q=SELECT+UserId+,+User.Username+,+HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber+,+HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress+,+HasSalesforceAuthenticator+,+HasTotp+,+HasU2F+from+TwoFactorMethodsInfo
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "message": "sObject type 'TwoFactorMethodsInfo' is not supported.",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_TYPE"
    }
]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in API permission to access this object. (Note that multi-factor authentication was formerly called two-factor authentication.)